# Почему при заполнении формы и нажатии на кнопку не прибавляются строки в таблице с данными ? JS

Tags: javascript, html, веб-программирование, frontend

имеется 2 документа. 1й :

`<form action="" id="add_persons" method="post" onsubmit="addRow();return false;">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Добавить сотрудника</legend>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <label for="name">Фамилия</label>
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" size="12" tabindex="1" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="initials">Инициалы</label>
                <input type="text" name="initials" id="initials" value="" size="12" tabindex="2" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="posada">Должность</label>
                <input type="text" name="posada" id="posada" value="" size="12" tabindex="3" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="subm">Действия</label>
                <input type="submit" name="subm" class="submit" value="Добавить" tabindex="4" />
            </li>
        </ul>
    </fieldset>`

2й:

`<table id="tab1" class="sortable">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>ФИО</th>
        <th>Должность</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>`

код js:
var d = document;

```
var name;
var initials;
var posada;

function addRow()
{
    // считываем значени¤ с формы
    name = d.getElementById('name').value;
    initials = d.getElementById('initials').value;
    posada = d.getElementById('posada').value;

    // находим нужную таблицу
    var tbody = d.getElementById('tab1').getElementsByTagName('TBODY')[0];

    // создаем строку таблицы и добавляем ее
    var row = d.createElement("TR");
    tbody.appendChild(row);

    // создаем ячейки в вышесозданной строке
    // и добавляем их
    var td1 = d.createElement("TD");
    var td2 = d.createElement("TD");

    row.appendChild(td1);
    row.appendChild(td2);

    // наполняем ячейки
    td1.innerHTML = name+' '+initials;
    td2.innerHTML = posada;
}
```

вопрос: почему при заполнении формы и нажатии на кнопку не прибавляются строки в таблице с данными ? как это можно исправить если не правильно ? Не могу сообразить. Разделение на 2 документа - обязательно.

Comment: Как ни странно, но всё работает. https://jsfiddle.net/4jboh00t/.
Обработчик должен возвращать false; И на всякий случай функцию следует объявить в глобальной области видимости. ```window.addRow = addRow;```

Comment: @peter Если в одном index.html документе сделать форму и таблицу и подключить к нему файл js, то да все работает ) но если поместить в разные документы (в один форму только, а во второй таблицу) , и подключить к каждому этот файл js , то при нажатии кнопки в документе где форма, во второй документ где таблица -  ничего не добавляется, не генерируется она.

Comment: Т.е. получается форма, и таблица у Вас на разных страницах, в таком случае Вам не обойтись без серверного скрипта, к примеру php, и хранилища информации: база данных, файлы. Опишите подробнее суть задачи.